# Python - Assign one element in list to every element in another list within a loop

Tags: python

I´m trying to sort through some files, where i first find the filename in my `dir` with  `glob.glob` ex. (filename1, filename2, filename3) so i get this list of files [(Filename1,), (Filename2,), (Filename3,)]

After this i have a for loop that with `.readline()` extracts a string from each file. So after every loop has ben executed, filename1 prints 10 strings, next loop filename2 prints 3 strings, next loop filename3 prints 5 strings .

```
loop
[string1]
[string2]
[string3]
.....
loop
[string1]
[string2]
[string3]
....
loop
[string1]
[string2]
[string3]
....
```

The problem is that i know that the 10 strings came from filename1 but i want to indicate that they did.

```
    How i would like it to look after print 
loop
[filename1 , string1]
[filename1 , string2]
[filename1 , string3]
    .......
new loop   
[filename2 , string1]
[filename2 , string2]
[filename2 , string3]
    .......
new loop
[filename3 , string1]
[filename3 , string2]
[filename3 , string3]
```

can someone help me or send me in the right direction? i have search for "assigning a list to a element in another list" and similar tags, but can´t find what i need... help is appreciated thanks!

EDIT

```
    with open (filename) as filesearch:
            filesearch = filesearch.readlines()
# ---------- Loop 1 for filename and filedate-----------------------------------
    for line in filesearch:
            if createdate in line:  # extract "Create Time"
                date = []
                file = []
                file.append(filename[42:])
                #print(file)
                date.append(line[15:])    # store all found filedates in array
                #print(date)
                list_logfile = list(zip(file,date))
                #print(list_logfile)


# ---------- Loop 2 for finding string ------------------------------------------------------
    for line in filesearch:
            if tester in line:  # extract "Sending Request: Tester"
                data = []
                message = []
                start = '-> '   # take string from
                end = ':\ '     # ens string at
                number = line[line.find(start) + 3: line.find(end)]  # [ord('-> '):ord(' :\ ')]
                data.append(number)  # store all found tester in a array
                text = line[line.find(end) + 3:]
                message.append(text)    # store all found comments in a array
                print(data)

    down here i want to append the first file filename1 to the frist loop of strings , 
then append filename2 with the next loop of strings, 
then the next and next...
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could post your loop

Comment: Use dictionaries maybe?

Comment: @RayhaneMama sure thing